# How to connect cordova with internal project localhost?

Tags: cordova

I want to do an application and I'm using cordova plugin innapbrowser for doing a progressive webapp.
But I want to open the browser to my localhost in my PC. 
When I run this, the localhost working (normally)

```
cordova run browser
```

When I trying this, I have a problem

```
cordova run android

"web page not found"
```

I think, I need to install the plugin httpd in cordova, but I dont know how to connect this plugin with the syntax of the pugin of innapbrowser

Comment: It seems like you don't have an index.html page in the application

Comment: So why then would it run on the browser platform..!?

Answer (score 1):

When you run on android, localhost refers to the android emulator or device, not to your computer.

If you want to access to a page located on your computer, you have to access to your computer's ip instead of localhost.